# PL/SQL insert record using max function

Tags: oracle, plsql

Create a PL/SQL block to insert a new record into the Department table. Fetch the maximum department id from the Department table and add 10 to it; take this value for department id; 'TESTING' is the value for department name and CHN-102 is the value for Location ID.

Note: Use '/' to terminate your query before compilation and evaluation

Table name : Department

```
Column name     | Data type    | Constraints
             
DEPARTMENT_ID   | NUMBER(5)    | PK
DEPARTMENT_NAME | VARCHAR2(25) | NOT NULL
LOCATION_ID     | VARCHAR2(15)
```

Sample Output:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME LOCATION_ID
------------- --------------- -----------
 XXXX         TESTING         CHN-102
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you described it, it would look like this:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_department_id      department.department_id%type;
  3    l_department_name    department.department_name%type  := 'TESTING';
  4    l_location_id        department.location_id%type      := 'CHN-102';
  5  begin
  6    select nvl(max(department_id), 10)
  7      into l_department_id
  8      from department;
  9
 10    insert into department (department_id, department_name, location_id)
 11      values (l_department_id + 10, l_department_name, l_location_id);
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From department;

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME      LOCATION_I
------------- -------------------- ----------
           20 TESTING              CHN-102

SQL>
```

Note, though, that `MAX + 10` is a wrong approach. If two (or more) users run the same procedure at the same time, only the first one who commits changes will be able to do that; other user(s) will violate the primary key constraint because that `department_id` already exists (as it was inserted moments ago by someone else). Use a **sequence** instead.